# What are the different ways to get the interview calls for Software Developer profile after an year gap?

Tags: interviewing, software-industry, job-search, software-development, fresher

I graduated from B.Tech in ECE from NIT Kurukshetra (2012-16). But I had two Backlogs in Engineering because of which I lost my on-campus job as a Software Developer.

*(In India, Backlog in a subject means a person is failed in that subject in a semester and it is referred as active backlog and when that person clears that subject, it is referred as dead backlog. In my college, there was a rule that if you have failed in a subject of odd/even semester, then you will again give the exam of that subject after one year in the next odd/even semester.)*

For the next two months after the final year, I was rejected in many off-campus interviews because of the active backlogs and then, I got a job as a Content Writer. I worked there for 7 months and then left the job and cleared the backlog exams recently in May 2017. 
Now, I am applying for the job of Software Developer but I'm unable to get even a single interview call.

I have contacted many friends on LinkedIn but 95% of the friends told me that there is no vacancy in their companies. I also tried applying on many job portals but still got no result. A few companies didn't shortlist my resume because of that year gap.

What should I do to get an interview call? Should I include the experience as a Content Writer in my resume which has no relevance to the Software Developer profile? Or should I look out for an internship?

Comment: purely FWIW I would not emphasize the "content writer", no.  Just one opinion though.

Comment: Oh - that's bad luck.  That would make it tough with the ultra-competitive academics in India.  thanks @sleske

Comment: Is it possible to get help from the school's careers advisors? Most businesses looking for zero developer experience graduates at this time of year are going to hire straight from school.

Comment: You are *assuming* that your backlog has to do with not getting a new job. Can you back that up with facts? Have people told you so, or been critical about it? Please [edit] that into your question as well.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan, No in my college, the career advisors help only those who graduate recently. For me, it has been over a year since leaving that college.

Comment: hi @JanDoggen. I don't see the OP assuming that (or anything) anywhere?  OP is just asking the question in the title.

Comment: "I have contacted many friends on LinkedIn but 95% of the friends told me that there is no vacancy in their companies." - Then go for the 5% where there are vacancies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing to do in your situation is to show the interviewers some activity in the software development field. You have to find a project to work on, be it a community project, something you develop because you need/want it, or even some freelancing.

What matters is being active, showing you actually know how to develop and are good at it.

Having this project on some personal GIT would probably help.

Comment: Quite right.  OP should freelance like crazy.

Comment: @Fattie That's the best compromise in his solution I think. He won't find big projects at first , but he'll get paid a little and he'll finaly get a feet back in the software business !

Comment: @Jan Doggen, actually I worked on a simple Android app during my college days as a part of a major project and I've included it in my resume. I'm also comfortable with C, C++, and Java and have been studying Data Structures and Algorithms in the past month.

Comment: @Jan Doggen, in India, it becomes extremely difficult for the freshers to take a job in IT industry with a big gap after graduation and with no prior experience. However, for the experienced people, this strategy works well.

Comment: hi @DG4 yes that's quite true.  I would urge you to **freelance like crazy**.  Also it's not good enough (no offense) you made some "simple" Android app.  You should have used all this time to make incredibly complex and amazing demo software (whether apps, github projects, or whatever is your thing).

Comment: @Fattie, should I include the Content Writer experience in my resume or show an employment gap instead?

Comment: Never add smth not relevant to the job you want in your CV , or include a simple line to let them know you didn't smth (1 line , more isn't needed).

And go freelancing , and try to find some big open source projects to work on. This will get you knew skills and make you attractive again for recruiters.

Comment: to let them know you did something*

Comment: hi @DG4 what sort of content was it?  did it relate to software?  If so, you could just make a brief entry "Documentation & Content Writer" or "Technical Writer".   my instinct would be to just not bother with it, probably  :/

Comment: @Fattie, the contents I wrote were related to the domain of Education, Travel, and Technical Support.